# Разделение строки google script

Tags: google-apps-script

подскажите пожалуйста.
Хочу разделить строку на части, допустим "медведь;пчела" на "медведь" и "пчела".
Можно ли это как-то реализовать, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps Script - это диалект JavaScript. Вы можете использовать все базовые методы языка.

Например, вы можете использовать метод `split` для строк. Чтобы получить эти значения в переменные нужно будет обратиться по индексу массива или указать деструктурирующее присваивание.

```js
function userRun() {
  const string = 'медведь;пчела';

  const split = string.split(';');
  const word11 = split[0];
  const word12 = split[1];

  const [word21, word22] = string.split(';');
  
  console.log(word11, word12, word21, word22);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]